# Data encryption safe even with developer access

Tags: security, encryption, cloud

Suppose you have a server-client application.

Server keeps sensitive information that belongs to a Client.
Server will search some parameters in side the clients's sensitive information.
Thus server should decode the sensitive information with client control temporarily.
But server should not reveal the keys, by hacking it self.
I mean a developer should not try to change server sidde code and should not extract the client keys.

Is there really a way to do that? 
Somewhat client permits server to decode sensitive information, but the keys instantly disappear and developer have no tricks to reveal this password?

The answer if exist, is valid also for an ideal secure cloud application. Developer or cloud hosting company should not access to decrypted information.

I am not optimistic, but worth to try asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in a word no.  This does not grant any security whatsoever, as you cannot trust the client.  You even call out that the server will be controlled by the client temporarily, this is generally not a wise approach.  Also, do not underestimate a bored developer, it is completely feasible to write some code and rip the keys.  The key here is remembering that if someone has access to the box it is no longer your box.

Comment: You are saying "The key here is remembering that if someone has access to the box it is no longer your box. ". So in otherwords; no any, even multi-billion companies offering cloud solutions cannot claim 100% security on customer data,other than good will and legal promises, unless the data is only and only encrypted and decrpyted at client side, right?

Comment: @freewill of course not.  Given enough time and /or resources anything is breakable.  They can offer things like 99.999999999% percent but never a hundred

Comment: So I come up with server needs to be ultimate trusted source, and clients should not take control over it. Additionally Server can olny be secured at customer field and customer responsibility. One last question; is standard dedicated server is an option? I mean if hosting company can access our "box" without our knowledge or permission?

Comment: @freewill if someone else manages your system, they surely can do with it what they want.

Answer (score 0):

In general, any client access to sensitive info on the server must require authentication of the client, so that you can verify that the client is exactly who he claims he his. The authentication typically involves sending a password, or some kind of authentication token (e.g., an encrypted shared secret) that was given to the client by the server through a secure channel.

As has been said many times, many ways, allowing client access to server data without proper and sufficient authentication means that you give up control of the server.